# How do you add The Pirate Bay scope?

Tags: 14.04, lenses, scopes

So, I've installed `unity-scope-piratebay`, but it doesn't work in 14.04. `unity-lens-torrents` is not published for trusty and even after installing from a .deb file it doesn't work. There is no lens and there is no filter.

Comment: Did you log out and back in?

Comment: No, I did not. Would it work?

Comment: Why not try it? It definitely wouldn't hurt. The install directions for previous releases says to do so

Comment: OK, I will try. Buy there was another question here on AskUbuntu. And they said that there is no lens, but you can search through tpb:name or torrents: name. They also said that this only works for a second and then the filter is not activated anymore.

Comment: OK, I've tried logging out, and I've got the same problem as noted above.